# How can we avoid rendering on adding navigation fragment

Tags: android, xml

I detect rendering problem on adding navigation fragment into my xml page how can remove this rendering problem

Comment: As a non-clairvoyant I'd say show your code so that we know what you are talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got to files and select invalid cache/restart then select invalid and restart option
It get solved my problem

Comment: Why should the OP do this? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.